# Что такое матрица трансляции и как ей пользоваться в OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: jni, android, c++, opengl

Пишу под Андроид. Суть в том, что `rotateM` вращает по оси x y z, а `translateM` не могу понять (что она делает). Нашёл пояснение на английском: Translate matrix m by x y z in place, но всё равно не пойму. Обьясните, пожалуйста.

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(mLightModelMatrix, 0);
Matrix.translateM(mLightModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);      
Matrix.rotateM(mLightModelMatrix, 0, angleInDegrees, 0.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f);
Matrix.translateM(mLightModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f);
```

Comment: слишком много кода. Много кода. Мне лично лень читать эти 5 страниц. Думаю, большинству других тоже. Локализуйте проблему.

Answer (score 1):

`translateM` сдвигает модель в сторону, соответственно осям X Y Z, *до* или *после* вращения. Порядок операций имеет значение.